# Как очень быстро найти строку в файле python

Tags: python, txt

У меня есть огромный файл txt формата (вес около 25 Гб) в нём определённые данные, мне нужно искать слово и если оно есть то выводить всю строку.
Какой самый быстрый способ поиска и вообще целесообразно использовать txt или может перевести в другой формат например csv для увеличения скорости чтения?
Кто поможет буду благодарен.

Comment: Упаковать в базу данных. Конкретный ответ зависит от того, какие конкретно у вас данные, есть ли у них структура? Иначе, что бы Вы не делали, у Вас будет только линейная скорость поиска

Answer (score 1):

вы, скорее всего под виндой, но есть пакет busybox https://busybox.net/
команда grep (осуществляет указанный в комментарии) линейный поиск:

```
cat /путь/файл.txt | grep "слово_для поиска" # либо регулярное выражение
grep "string" file.txt
```

небольшая статья https://habr.com/ru/articles/229501/

если требуется регулярная выборка, то, действительно, лучше занести данные в базу данных. если вы начинающий, можете попробовать sqlite, h2, hsqldb

Comment: А зачем конвейер? `grep "слово_для поиска" /путь/файл.txt` сделает то же самое, только быстрее

Comment: ну, например, когда идёт затем еще 2-3 поиска, одним запросом я ищу и подкрашиваю красным error, потом зелёным OK-success. и вуаля, визуальный мониторинг критического ресурса. вместо cat стоит tail -f файл.txt|

Answer (score 0):

как вариант - использовать подход MapReduce. То есть, разбить файл на(допустим) сотню поменьше. Распараллелить обработку(с asyncio) каждого файла. Затем объединить данные.
можно воспользоваться не asyncio а чем-то более знакомым -threading/multiprocessing

Comment: Если не раскидывать файлы по разным физическим носителям (желательно на разных интерфейсах), то imho  такой подход может лишь замедлить задачу, поскольку основное время тут будет тратиться на чтение данных с диска, а последовательное чтение (без перемещения головок) на порядок быстрее

Comment: если не использовать что-то наподобие облачной службы, то да, согласен.

Comment: С облачной службой (если, конечно, у вас не кластер с infiniband) вы в лучшем случае получите скорость в половину сырой скорости сетевого интерфейса (хорошо если это будет мегабайт 50 в секунду)

Comment: почему? 32 ядра 65 гигов, расп-ть и все.  как пример -> https://aws.amazon.com/ru/ec2/

Comment: Ваш комп (там где запущена программа, которая читает файл(ы) и ищет слово) подключен к облачной службе через сетевой интерфейс. Никакие данные от самой лучшей облачной службы (даже если ваши данные уже находятся там в памяти (в файловом кэше)) не попадут к вам быстрее, чем может пропустить интерфейс. Скорость сетевого интерфейса на порядок меньше скорости передачи из памяти в процессор.  Поэтому количество ядер тут ни при чем. Скорость будет определяться самым медленным звеном в цепи передачи. А половина скорости интерфейса, это эмпирика (из личного опыта)

Comment: спасибо! я только один раз, если начистоту, работал с параллельными вычислениями и из этого опыта отталкиваюсь. был датасет и в нем нужно было прочитать все строки и посчитать сколько слов начинается в каждой строке с определенного символа. я использовал методику  MapReduce и asyncio c кластером aws. Ваш комментарий весьма познавателен, еще раз спасибо!